# How do you deal with random URLs when using Selenium in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So I was trying to make an automation script for a website called [Quia](https://quia.com). Although the problem is, whenever you go to a new page in the website and such, it generates a random new URL. I think this is making my code not be able to function. Is there any way to get around this? Here is my code:

```
'''
This is a program that will complete any quia quizzes for you. 

How it works:
    1. First it will complete many quizzes entering random answers.
    2. Then it will complete a quiz, and use the answers it is given from the other quizzes.

How it is powered:
    1. It uses the Selenium webdriver.
    2. It uses the BeautifulSoup library.

Steps to build:
    1. Get users information.
    2. Access Chrome using Selenium and BeautifulSoup.
    3. Go to the selected quiz
    4. Login with user credentials
    5. Open the quiz and complete it with random answers, leave tab open.
    6. Repeat steps 4, 5, and 6 for as many times as the user wants.
    7. Open a final quiz.
    8. Use the answers from other quizzes for the final quiz.
    9. Show user their score and close any tabs that the program opened.

'''

# Import libraries, selenium, and beautifulsoup
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Complete step 1:
# Get users information
creds_username = input("Enter your username: ")
creds_password = input("Enter your password: ")
info_quiz_count = int(input("How many practice quizzes do you want to complete? "))
info_quiz_url = input("Enter the url of the quiz you want to complete: ")

# Complete step 2:
# Access Chrome using Selenium and BeautifulSoup.
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

# Complete step 3:
# Go to the selected quiz in a new tab
def open_quiz(browser, info_quiz_url):
    browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't') 
    browser.get(info_quiz_url)

# Complete step 4:
# Login with users credentials
def login(browser, creds_username, creds_password):
    username = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('[name="tag_quiz_username"]')
    username.send_keys(creds_username)
    password = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('[name="tag_quiz_password"]')
    password.send_keys(creds_password)
    login_button = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('[name="tagStartQuiz"]')
    login_button.click()

# Complete step 5:
# Answer with random answers. If it is multiple choice, choose the first one. If it is text, enter "This is a test."

def practice(browser):
    # If it is a text question:
    try: 
        # Find the text input box
        text_input = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'tq_g_')]")
        # Enter "This is a test"
        text_input.send_keys("This is a test.")
    except:
        print("Can't find text input box, trying multiple choice.")
    else:
        # If it is a multiple choice question:
        # Find the first multiple choice input box
        multiple_choice_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("[id$='guess_0']")
        # Click it
        multiple_choice_input.click()
    # Click submit
    submit_button = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('[name="tag_submit_one_at_a_time"]')
    
# Complete step 6:
# Repeat steps 4, 5, and 6 for as many times as the user wants.
for i in range(info_quiz_count):
    open_quiz(browser, info_quiz_url)
    login(browser, creds_username, creds_password)
    practice(browser)
```

Sorry for bad code, I am new to this stuff and just trying to find my way around.